# Replacing volatile with synchronized block is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I was going through [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0) tutorial. I understood the volatile keyword usage. But when i tried to achieve same result without using volatile keyword with doing operation on the concern variable with in synchronized block, it is not working. It throws IllegalMonitorStateException. Here is the modified code i tried.

```
public class VolatileTest {
private static Integer MY_INT = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChangeListener().start();
    new ChangeMaker().start();
}

static class ChangeListener extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         synchronized(MY_INT){
        int local_value = MY_INT;
        while ( local_value < 5){
            if( local_value!= MY_INT){
                System.out.format("Got Change for MY_INT : {0}", MY_INT);
                 local_value= MY_INT; 
                  try {
                MY_INT.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
            }
        }
    }
}

static class ChangeMaker extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
         synchronized(MY_INT){
        int local_value = MY_INT;
        while (MY_INT <5){
            System.out.format("Incrementing MY_INT to {0}", local_value+1);
            MY_INT = ++local_value;
            try {
                MY_INT.notify();
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}}}
```

What I want to know is, in this case is volatile replaceable with synchronized block, if yes then how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 MY_INT = ++local_value;
```

`MY_INT` is an `Integer` variable, and when you assign a new value to it, the object that you are locking here:

```
 synchronized(MY_INT){
```

will be different to the object that you are notifying here:

```
  MY_INT.notify();
```

... and that will lead to the exception.

---

The solution is to make the lock object `static final`.  Obviously that means you can't assign to it ... but that is the whole point!

Comment: Good answer, except that the immutability of Integer objects is not the problem.  Any time you have a variable `Foo foo;`, and you assign to it `foo = ...;`, that updates the object reference.  It doesn't matter whether the `Foo` class is immutable or not.

Comment: Yeah, but a noob could easily misinterpret what you said, "Integer objects are immutble.  When you assign to an Integer variable...".  That's two independent clauses, but when you put them in the same paragraph, somebody who's not familiar with the language might remember it as if you'd said, _because_ Integer objects are immutable...