# Why isn't this synchronized statement example working?

Tags: java, multithreading

Playing with synchronization, I basically have two cuncurrent threads executing a method of the same object, but probably I'm getting something wrong.

Given this piece of code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        new Test();
    }

    Test() throws InterruptedException{

        Stuff s = new Stuff();

        Th t1 = new Th(1,s);
        Th t2 = new Th(2,s);

        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Stuff{
    public Integer count=0;

    void doStuff(int threadId){
        System.out.println(threadId + ": in doStuff");
        synchronized (count) {
            count += 100;

            if (threadId == 1) {
                try {Thread.sleep(3000);} 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }

            System.out.println(threadId + ": count = " + count);
        }
    }
}

class Th extends Thread{

    public Stuff s;
    public int id;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(id+": thread run");
        s.doStuff(id);
    }

    Th(int id_,Stuff s_){
        s=s_;
        id=id_;
        System.out.println(id+": thread created");
    }
}
```

I get this output

```
    1: thread created
    2: thread created
    1: thread run
    1: in doStuff
    2: thread run
    2: in doStuff
    2: count = 200
    1: count = 200
```

Why is `t1` printing "200"? 
Shouldn't `t2` wait for `t1` to execute the synchronized block before being able to get the lock on `count` and then execute the block?

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but the same underlying problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385516/replacing-volatile-with-synchronized-block-is-not-working/29385784#29385784 (I knew I saw a similar question recently)

Comment: By the way, your naming style has some issue. `id_` is not good, just use `id` and `this.id=id`.

Comment: @EricWang I know that, but to be honest that's the only convention I never really liked. That's my personal little form of rebellion against the system =)

Comment: @LuigiCortese That's more like c style, but, yeah, it's your choice.

Comment: There's a rule of thumb that will stop you from making that mistake (see @Thilo's answer):  Whenever you write `synchronized(foo){...}`, you should make `foo` a `final` field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 synchronized (count) {
        count += 100;
```

That does not work.

You are synchronizing on Objects, not on variables or fields.

Every time you increase the `count`, that field will point at a different `Integer` object. So your synchronized block uses a different monitor all the time.

You need to find a "stable" lock object, for example

```
 private final Object lockMonitor = new Object();
```

(then you can say `synchronized (lockMonitor){}` instead)

Comment: It's a little unclear (to me) what to do with that. Do you just replace `synchronize (count)` with `synchronize (lockMonitor)` and then don't need to do anything else with the `lockMonitor`? Or do you need to modify that object within the `synchronize` block?

Comment: Yes, you can then synchronize on the lockMonitor. And you don't have to do anything else with it. In fact, you should not. It's just there so that you have something (private) to lock on.

Comment: Or if `count` was, say, a `StringBuffer`, you could keep `synchronize (count)` and append new value in the synchronized block, for instance. I think it this case you should get the same result without extra objects

Comment: That's right. If you are going that route, I'd use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a `StringBuffer` though. That's Java's version of a mutable Integer.